# How to calculate average age members

Tags: templating, filter

We are building a family community website with 600+ members.

One of the gimmicks will be some stats, like average age all members.

Is there a smart way to calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{# Get all members #}
{% set members = craft.users().limit(null) %}

{# Get total number of members #}
{% set memberCount = members.total() %}

{# Set this outside the 'for' loop so you can use it later #}
{% set ageSum = 0 %}

{# Add 'em up #}
{# We assume here you have a custom member field with the handle 'age' #}
{% for member in members %}
    {% set ageSum = ageSum + member.age %} 
{% endfor %}

{# Get the average #}
{% set avgAge = ageSum / memberCount %}

{# Print it #}
<p>Average member age is {{ avgAge }}<p>
```

If you want to limit the calculation to a particular user group, just add its handle to the end of the first `set`.

```
{% set members = craft.users().group('groupHandle') %}
```

If `age` is not a required field you might want to skip records that don't have an `age`. I'm not entirely sure what including them would do to the math.

```
{% set ageSum = (member.age and member.age > 0) ? ageSum + member.age : ageSum %}
```

Comment: Philip, in your example you don't add .limit(x) to it. If I leave that out, I only get 100 results. Is there a way to disable this default limit of 100?

Comment: @JohnStevens, you can add `.limit(null)` to the criteria in order to return all users – i.e. `{% set members = craft.users().limit(null) %}`.

Comment: Actually, I'll edit the question to include it :)

Comment: I also made the assumption of an `age` field, versus the far more logical `birthdate` field. But it should be easy enough to replace all my `age` field references with an age calculation based on the `birthdate`.

Comment: And thanks @MatsMikkelRummelhoff for updating with `.limit(null)`. I always forget to account for the 100-record limit. Good call.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will exactly answer your question, but I think it will help get you going in the right direction.

Within my application, I am grabbing entries that belong to the currently logged in user - finding the fields and then displaying an average distance.

If you'll notice I am setting a `level': 2` in my parameters. That's because I am working with a structure and the first level is the "parent" entry that does not have any of the data I am attempting to average.

```
{# Get all of the entries entered by the user. #}
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    'section': 'mySection',
    'level': 2,
    'descendantOf': user.id
}) %}

{% if entries|length %}

    ...

    {% set value = 0 %}
    {% set count = 0 %}

    {% for entry in entires %}
        {% set value = value + entry.distance %}
        {% set count = loop.index %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% set averageDistance = (value / count)|round(1, 'floor') %}

    <p>Avg: {{ averageDistance }}</p>

    ...

{% else %}
    {# Could not find any entries. #}
{% endif %}
```

So in a nutshell, you'll want to:

- grab the entries from the appropriate section
- find the field(s) you want to average ex: distance
- do math
- return the result

For you (this is a stab in the dark) you would want to get all users, get the value of the `age` field. Then loop over to get your `count` and divide that by the ages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Damon, your example gave me insight on how to do it.

`{% set totaal = craft.users.group('leden').limit(5000)|length %}
{% set sumage = 0 %}
{% for age in craft.users.group('leden').limit(5000) %}
 {% set sumage = sumage + age.geboortedatum.diff(now).format('%y') %}
{% endfor %}
Avg: {{ (sumage / totaal)|round  }}
`